# Looking for an "Zoom"-effect event handler for UICollectionViewCell in tvOS

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, tvos

I have to do something in case of a `UICollectionViewCell` will be zoom out (hover state).

I thought that this effect updates the bounds of the cell and I've overridden the bound variable.

But the `didSet`method will be only triggered for the first time (original size) and not for the new size during the zooming.

```
override var bounds: CGRect
{
    didSet
    {
        // do some magic
    }
}
```

What would be the correct way catch this kind of event?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just the transform property of the view that changes, this would not trigger a bounds change, so perhaps watch the transform property or the transform property of the view's layer. The problem with a layer transform change is that you probably may not observe a change there.

Comment: Neither the transform property will be called nor the constrains will be updated during the effect. :/